# iOS Pinterest API share callback

Tags: ios, pinterest

I am needing some help. I'm using the Pinterest API to add a new pin, from an iOS app. My code is the following:

```
 NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.myUrl];
 NSURL *sourceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.myUrl];
 [self.pinterest createPinWithImageURL:imageURL sourceURL:sourceURL description:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Try\n %@",self.comments.text]];
```

Now I need to detect when (and if) the pin has been created. Is it possible? I was not able to found any informations in the documentation.

Comment: When I integrated the pinterest, after I create a pin and post it, the `-(BOOL)handleOpeURL:(NSURL*)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplciation annotation:(id)annotation` is called and the `URL` scheme is `pinYourAppId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. `createPinWithImageURL:sourceURL:description:` has no return value and there's no protocol you can implement to receive the identifier of the pin you just created.

Comment: is there any other way to pin image with call back to my sharing app ?? after pin the image i want to return to my app.